# Parse push notifications broken in iOS 9 build with updated frameworks

Tags: ios, xcode, push-notification

I'm trying to conceptually understand how I broke my push notifications in iOS 9.

Here's what actions I took:

1. I updated the Parse and Bolts frameworks from 1.6.1 to 1.8.3 by deleting the old frameworks in Xcode and deleting the actual files in the finder. Then I added the new versions of the frameworks into the project by dragging them into Xcode. I checked the build phases and the new libraries are linked.
2. At this point I tested the app and was not receiving notifications with this build. People running previous versions of the app on iOS 9 do receive notifications.
3. I had not changed the App ID or Provisioning Profile at this point, but I thought they could be the issue, so I created a new Provisioning Profile with the existing App ID. Still no notifs.
4. I checked in Parse Core and my device is registering with the correct build # and the updated Parse library. So Parse knows my device needs to be sent a push, but it's not getting there.

Normally I would expect the advice to be create a new Provisioning Profile, but I did that. Any idea what I might be missing here? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Since you did all of that, I would like to note that Push notifications are **not** guaranteed to be sent, they just usually are. And Parse Push has gone down before. So if not tonight, try again tomorrow. However, I would try a couple more things, ensure your client-push is enabled in your Parse.com console. I would also delete the app and reinstall and also make sure your code signing is accurate in your project settings. You should also try a simple Clean in Xcode, sometimes that does a lot of good. At most, you could try building an Ad Hoc version to test. Lastly, they have summarized a couple of more things you can troubleshoot since this a common issue and they use their Google Groups for developer communications now more-so than SO : https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/parse-developers/65WAfRIiEnA

Note: This is not a one-answer fix, since push notifications don't have a one-specific issue. But these are general outlines of what can be done to remedy your particular issue. I have two apps with Parse, running Xcode 7 GM and iOS 9 GM and push notifications are working for both.

Answer (score 0):

Simply using an ad hoc build (ie with production push certificates) rather than deploying from xCode (with development certs) resolved this. If your app is already deployed in production in Parse, you will have replaced the development certs in their dashboard when you released it.